# How to select specific date from date picker in UFT 12.05?

Tags: date, hp-uft

I want to select the Date from date picker where data is passing from outside uft i.e xls files,here i'm facing the problem i.e unable to select particular date i.e for example:

25-Aug-1960,in this one i'm able to select Aug and 1960 but unable to select 25 from date picker,please help how to resolve this issue.

```
Wait(4)
Browser("Customer Managemen").Page("Manage Customer_2").WebEdit("birthDate").Click
Browser("Customer Managemen").Page("Manage Customer_2").WebList("Year").Select "1950"
wait(2)
Browser("Customer Managemen").Page("Manage Customer_2").WebList("Month").Select "Aug"
Browser("Customer Managemen").Page("Manage Customer_2").Link("Dno").Click
```

Here **Dno** means -2 in date picker.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the application where you are setting the date? Also, are you selecting the date from a weblist or setting it in a webedit?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this answer here: [Automating Date Control using QTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209843/automating-date-control-using-qtp)

Also, use the below code as reference to change it

```
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").Frame("DatePicker").highlight
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").Frame("DatePicker").WebList("Month").Select "Jan"
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").Frame("DatePicker").WebList("Year").Select "2015"
Set A = Browser("Browser").Page("Page").Frame("DatePicker").Link("1")
A.SetTOProperty "text",11
A.Click
```